# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.* since upgrading to Support Library v23

Tags: android, android-widget, android-support-library, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using [MaterialDialog](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) library in my app.
Yesterday I've updated the library version to its latest, and since it's using some new annotations, I had to update the `Support V7` library as well.
Ever since, no screen with widget (`CheckBox` / `RadioButton`) can be loaded.
Here is the stack :

```
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341): Process: com.xx.xxx, PID: 30341
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:89)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:886)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:940)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.preference.Preference.onCreateView(Preference.java:516)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:487)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:246)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2150)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15595)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15595)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15595)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15595)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15595)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15595)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15595)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15595)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15595)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5786)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
08-30 21:53:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(30341):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayE
```

Same goes for `AppCompatRadioButton`too.

I have tried removing / deleting / re-adding the support library
I have also tried to revert the MaterialDialog library to its older version, no success either
I've also added `CheckBox` to simple `PreferenceFragment` and the same exception was raised.

I'm using eclipse, not Android Studio.

Comment: Same happened to me with Android Studio.
However do the porting asap, I didn't want too, but then after a couple of weeks in Android Studio, developing was much much better :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to manually copy the new version of *android-sdk\extras\android\support\v13\android-support-v13.jar* into your *libs* folder.

If you used Android Studio you could use *compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.0'* or *:23+* instead of copying it.

**Not only**, using Eclipse, if you have others support jars in libs, you should update them by copying them manually too.